# touch events not firing in safari desktop

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, touch-event

I'm developing an app that would support touch events on desktop and mobile devices.
when using something like (per https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html )

```
element.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
element.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, false);
element.addEventListener("touchend", touchEnd, false);
element.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchCancel, false);
```

these only fire when testing on ipad and iphone, not on desktop. Since I'm developing on desktop, how could I make so these events are recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could view your website in iOS simulator, that is included in XCode on MacOs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: any chance you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888133/touchmove-event-on-mobile-safari-causes-the-whole-page-to-be-dragged

Answer (score 1):

On the test machines we use [phantom limb](http://www.vodori.com/blog/phantom-limb.html) to simulate touches. It's easy to setup and also won't do anything if the device supports touch natively.

Otherwise follow Alexey's advice and use the Simulator and a real device as often as possible.