# touchMove event on mobile safari - causes the whole page to be dragged

Tags: javascript, ios, html, webkit, touch

when applying touch events as per apple documentation

```
element.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
element.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, false);
element.addEventListener("touchend", touchEnd, false);
element.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchCancel, false);
```

and dragging, the whole html page (on ipad or iphone) tends to be dragged along. How do I prevent that?

I tried adding

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to the callbacks, as well as

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
```

with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use preventing default action with returning false from a handler.

```
event.preventDefault();
return false;
```

Also you can try to use `event.stopPropagation();`

I think one of that should work